# iOS creating complex JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit-0.20

I have been struggling with this issue for some time now and I cant figure out why the JSON serialization is not working. What seems to be a simple task it taking way too long.

I have my model classes listed below. User object has NSArray of Education and Employment objects.

I am using RestKit and all of the relationships have been made and I can see that the dictionary of the parameters is being made the data is correct. In order to debug the issue further I am making JSON using the following code.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [RKObjectParameterization parametersWithObject:self.user requestDescriptor:delegate.postUserRequestDescriptor error:&error];

    // Serialize the object to JSON
    BOOL isTurnableToJSON = [NSJSONSerialization
                             isValidJSONObject: parameters];
    if(isTurnableToJSON){
        NSData *JSON = [RKMIMETypeSerialization dataFromObject:parameters MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON error:&error];
    }
```

isTurnableToJSON is always "NO". When I force creation of JSON I get the following error.

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Education)'
```

The same error is also thrown for employment if I remove the relationship of Education with user.

Here is my user, education, and location models.

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *first_name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *middle_name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *last_name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *profile_picture;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *display_name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *education;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *employment;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *skills;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *about_you;
@end

@interface Education : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *graduation_date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *major;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *degree;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Location *location;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *current;
@end

@interface Location : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *country;
@end
```

At this point I am at lose of any ideas and any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** RestKit Relationship mapping.

```
RKObjectMapping *locationMap = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:(Location.class)];
[locationMap addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"city":@"city",@"state":@"state",@"country":@"country"}];

RKObjectMapping *educationMap = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:(Education.class)];
[educationMap addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@ { @"name":@"name",@"graduation_date":@"graduation_date",@"major":@"major", @"degree":@"degree",@"current":@"current"}];
[educationMap addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"location" toKeyPath:@"location" withMapping:locationMap]];

RKObjectMapping *employmentMap =[RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:(Employment.class)];
[employmentMap addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"company":@"company",@"occupation":@"occupation", @"start_date":@"start_date",@"end_date":@"end_date",@"current":@"current"}];


RKObjectMapping *userPutRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[userPutRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:putUserMap];

[userPutRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"education" toKeyPath:@"education" withMapping:[educationMap inverseMapping]]];
[userPutRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"employment" toKeyPath:@"employment" withMapping:[employmentMap inverseMapping]]];



USER PUT REQUEST

    [objectManager addRequestDescriptor:[RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userPutRequestMapping
                                                                              objectClass:[User class]
                                                                              rootKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   method:RKRequestMethodPUT]];
```

Comment: What is the actual problem with restkit?

Comment: RestKit gives the same error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Education)'

Comment: Show your mappings then, you should be converting the `Education` instances to their component key/value pairs, not adding the whole object.

Comment: I would look into the RKRequestDescriptor you're providing.  It looks like it doesn't know how to parameterize the Education object.

Comment: shouldn't relationship take care of it? The exact same mapping works flawlessly for all GET calls its just POST which is causing issues.

Comment: Figured it out. The issue was combination of using wrong object for RKObjectMapping and also mistakenly adding NSDictionary as the class type for mapping.  =(